# How to test SSL cert for Android <= 2.2 compatibility

Tags: android, scripting, ssl

Android 2.2 and below have limits in what SSL certificates they trust. I would like to automatically test my certificates to see if they are Android 2.2 compatible.

Is there a way to do this with a script (shell, python, whatever)?

Comment: Could this be achieved with an emulator and a series of webviews?